# annotate data set, by training a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a [dataset](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) of 5331 positive and 5331 negative reviews. I want to mark Intensity of each review. Intensity can either be "0" or "1".
Is their any technique that I can manually mark 1000 reviews and train a classifier. If the classifier performs very good (say 90% s-fold validation) then I can fill the remaining review using the classifier's output? Will it be a justified assumption to fill 1/10th of data manually and predict the remaining?

I am new to Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you are looking for is **sentiment analysis** and is a well known problem in machine learning society. It is one of the easier tasks of NLP classification, so with great probability you can achieve even more than 90% accuracy. In general scors of 10-CV are a quite reasonable approximation of the real classifier's behaviour, assuming big enough dataset. There are also other (often considered better) techniques, like those based on bootstrap - google for Err^0.632 for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was aware of sentiment analysis and Opinion mining. My ques here was more related to marking the training values with the appropriate labels. I want to use the above dataset for training and use the learned model on some other dataset. Training set have 10k reviews and marking them manually was a bit tedious task. I will check out "Err^0.632"